# View WordPress images in Android Gallery

Tags: images, gallery, picasa

With my Android tablet, the Gallery shows images from an old Blogger blog that I used to use (the blog belongs to my Google account, obviously).

I currently have a WordPress blog hosted on my own web space, and I would really like to have the same functionality--some way to have the images that are hosted on my WordPress blog show up in my Gallery.

Is there any way to do this currently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

The blogger images showed up because they're hosted in Picasa which is integrated into the Android gallery.

But as a workaround you could host your images on Picasa and link to them from your blog.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can allways make an app that pulls the pictures from an rss feed or php webservice from the site and then shows them up